# How to install Jira on Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5?

Tags: jira, websphere-liberty

I have downloaded Jira and its comes integrated with tomcat. So when I run start-jira.sh it automatically starts the tomcat server on the mentioned port. Now I want to install the Jira Application on the WebSphere Liberty Profile.

How do I install Jira on Websphere Liberty Profile v 8.5?

Answer (score 1):

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Installing+JIRA+WAR for more information about this. But Websphere doesn't seem to have been supported since JIRA 4.2 (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Installing+JIRA+on+IBM+Websphere+6.x)